# Automatic column align along colons in Xcode and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting

Is there a macro or preference setting that would automatically align method parameters along the columns and colons in Xcode?

Basically a shortcut to turn this:

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam another:theOtherValue something:theSomethingValue else:theElseValue];
```

automatically into this:

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam 
                another:theOtherValue 
              something:theSomethingValue 
                   else:theElseValue];
```

Is it possible to get this working with code completion? In other words when I tab complete a method it would automatically wrap the formatting into this style? And what about preexisting code? Can I put my caret inside a method, press a keyboard shortcut and auto format the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are trying to accomplish is turning the following

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam another:theOtherValue something:theSomethingValue else:theElseValue];
```

Into something more readable such as

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam
                another:theOtherValue
              something:theSomethingValue
                   else:theElseValue];
```

This can be accomplished by pressing the `return` key immediately before each pseudo-argument. For example, press return where `<return>`is shown.

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam <return>another:theOtherValue <return>something:theSomethingValue <return>else:theElseValue];
```

If executed properly, the colons should align.

```
[object methodWithParam:theParam<return>
                another:theOtherValue<return>
              something:theSomethingValue<return>
                   else:theElseValue];
```

Comment: You can also cut and paste the misaligned lines in place. (Provided you had a newline after each arg)

Comment: Or just select the block of text and choose Re-Indent from the Editor menu. (I *think* that's where it is. It's control-i regardless.) Check Xcode preferences to make sure the relevant indentation options are on, too.